After upgrading httpd-2.4.41 to httpd-2.4.58, facing net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED error while uploading large file
Due to CVE-2021-40438 exploit on our old Apache, we had to upgrade from httpd-2.4.41 to httpd-2.4.58.
We face an issue when posting, since we are unable to upload files of more than a GB which will return error as net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED after approximately 60 seconds. Tried with smaller files which gets uploaded without any issue. We suspect if its something related to configuring timeout or any other parameter change. Any pointers here will be greatly appreciated.
Found these in apache error logs:
[Thu May 02 05:56:16.755033 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 19195] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Thu May 02 06:00:20.901284 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19195] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

If that helps

How is this problem related to PHP?

Have you first of all checked if the error log has anything to say about this?

@CBroe
Did not find anything on error logs. Looks like we need to extend the timeout, as am able to upload smaller size files without any issue. The file we intend to upload requires more than 2-3 mins of time

@CBroe any specific error log you are referring?
